# How can I 'stamp' a fingerprint onto an object's geometry for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing, displacement

I need to make a pendant (jewelry) with a fingerprint pressed into it — this will then be 3D printed (see image attached for an example of what I'm looking for).

Am I correct in thinking that a displacement modifier is the way to go? I have the image of the fingerprint which I was then going to use as the displacement modifier on the object. I have tested this out and it works to a certain extent but I was just wondering if there was a better method for doing this?

Many thanks in advance for any help or advice on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would think displacement is the way to go. An alternative would be to try making a textured sculpt brush with the texture set to stencil and use Dyntopo.

Comment: Hi @Brenticus, thanks for the alternative suggestion. I'm not incredibly familiar with the textured sculpt brush — would it allow me to replicate my fingerprint image or would it just give a close approximation? Reason I ask is because basically the fingerprint image I'm using is the fingerprint of the actual person I'm creating it for, hence it needs to closely resemble it. Hope that makes sense? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an image of the fingerprint of the person. If the image is high contrast, as in ridges are light, valleys are dark, then you can use it as a texture for a sculpt brush. If you change the brush mapping from tiled to Stencil, the image will be an overlay over your object. you can then position the image over the object where you want the point to be, then sculpt over it. The light areas will be affected more than the dark areas, giving the pattern. Using dyntop will only add more geometry where it is needed and can give more precise results.

Comment: Excellent info — thank you. I'm going to try this right now...

Comment: Just tried it, albeit very quickly, but it produced very good results. Thank you for the suggestion. Here's some quick renders --> (https://ibb.co/bEi5VG)